# Know how to fix this Unity Terrain Trees/Details clipping issue?

Tags: unity-game-engine, clipping, unity3d-terrain

I know Unity Terrain isn’t the most robust thing but has anyone ever seen this issue where a plane (in this case, the water) clips trees/details at certain angles?

I had the same issue with a particle effect that I was able to fix by creating a unique Sorting Layer, but Sorting Layers in 3D...?

Anyway, I have never seen this one before, so hopefully, one of you knows how to fix it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your water transparent?

I had this problem and it was because the water's transparency shader was rendering in front of the detail transparency shader.

I haven't found a solution so far. I just switched my water to an opaque shader...

Try switching your water to opaque. If that fixes the problem than you know it's a problem with the detail/water transparency shader.

Comment: I agree, it looks like some of his sprite renderers are overlapping others. He should check all order in layer settings

Answer (score 0):

This was posted a long time ago. However for any future visit, you can fix this by changing the render queue of the water to be geometry based instead of from shader.